# De raise a query postgres

Tags: array, postgresql, matrices, foreach, función-personalizada

Quería saber como puedo pasar este DO a función y que me ejecute la query en bucle del array.

```
DO 
$do$
DECLARE 
    x numeric[];
    arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
BEGIN

    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
    LOOP 
        RAISE notice 'WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM ways
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM ways)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    ways,

                   ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%,%), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            ))' ,x[1], x[2];
        END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

Con esto me hace la query con cada subgrupo del ARRAY, pero solo me lo muestra en "messages" y yo lo que quiero es que me ejecute la query con cada uno de los subgrupos del ARRAY que hago en la declaración.

A ver si alguien me puede orientar o ayudar en preparar el DO.

Answer (score 0):

utiliza la opción EXECUTE para ejecutar la query, creo que debereas poner el resultado en alguna variable en tu caso quedaria algo como esto:

```
DO 
$do$
DECLARE 
x numeric[];
arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
rec record;
BEGIN

FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
LOOP 
    RAISE notice 'WITH
        vertices AS (
            SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
            WHERE id IN (
                SELECT source FROM ways
                UNION
                SELECT target FROM ways)
        ),
        dijkstra AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                ways,

               ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%,%), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
        ))' ,x[1], x[2];
--EXECUTE

EXECUTE format('WITH
        vertices AS (
            SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
            WHERE id IN (
                SELECT source FROM ways
                UNION
                SELECT target FROM ways)
        ),
        dijkstra AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                ways,

               ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point($1,$2), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
        ))') using  x[1], x[2] into rec;


    END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero gracias a su respuesta.
Me salta un error de "function inline_code_block line 29 at EXECUTE", supongo que será porque no le he puesto ningun return.
Pero mi pregunta ahora sería como implementar este DO para crear una función. 
Que me haga esta función

```
SELECT *
            FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
                ways,

               ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
        )
```

tantas veces como subconjunto de ARRAYS haya ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM ARRAY [[[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]]
```

He tenido que poner el comentario en la respuesta porque no me daban los caractéres, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

es probable que tu sentencia with no esta bien formada o mejor dicho bien terminada(creo que le falta al final del with, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html ), pues por ejemplo si hago esto funciona:

```
DO 
$do$
 DECLARE 
 x numeric[];
 arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
 rec record;
BEGIN

FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
LOOP 
RAISE notice 'WITH
    vertices AS (
        SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT source FROM ways
            UNION
            SELECT target FROM ways)
    ),
    dijkstra AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
            ways,

           ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%,%), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
    ))' ,x[1], x[2];
 --EXECUTE

EXECUTE format('select $1,$2') using  x[1], x[2] into rec;

raise notice 'rec :% ', rec;


END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

ahora si lo que requieres es crear una funcion con ese codigo quedaria algo como esto:

```
create or replace function pacman () returns void -- en caso de retornar algo debes poner el tipo  de dato a retornar aca
as 
$$
DECLARE 
x numeric[];
arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
rec record;
BEGIN

FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr

LOOP 
 RAISE notice 'x : %, y: % ' ,x[1],x[2];
 --EXECUTE
 SELECT * into rec --debes poner la salida de llamada en una funcion, en este caso rec
         FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
            ways,

           ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x[1],x[2]), 4258) 
      LIMIT 1)]
     );

RAISE notice 'rec : % ' ,rec;


END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

si lo que quieres es retornar un conjunto de datod debes hacer las función de tipo setof y agrega el return next dentro del ciclo de la función.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que ese create function se acerca mucho al resultado que espero. La he modificado un poco para que me haga la función con el "WITH":

```
create or replace function pacman () returns void -- en caso de retornar algo debes poner el tipo  de dato a retornar aca
as 
$$
DECLARE 
x numeric[];
arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
rec record;
BEGIN

FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr

LOOP 
 RAISE notice 'x : %, y: % ' ,x[1],x[2];
 --EXECUTE
         WITH
    vertices AS (
        SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT source FROM ways
            UNION
            SELECT target FROM ways)),

        dijkstra as ( SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
            'ways',

           ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x[1],x[2]), 4258) 
      LIMIT 1)]
     ))
 SELECT * into rec --debes poner la salida de llamada en una funcion, en este caso rec
         FROM dijkstra;

RAISE notice 'rec : % ' ,rec;


END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Ahora como usted bien ha dicho, necesito que a la función metiéndole cualquier ARRAY de coordenadas vaya haciendo mi función. Exactamente que se vayan sumando a mi Query :

```
--Consulta de la función resultante de "create function"
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia('ways', ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];

--Trabajo que tiene que hacer la función en LOOP
WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM vehiculo_distancia
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM vehiculo_distancia)),

dijkstra AS (
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia('vehiculo_distancia', ARRAY[
            (SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.559516429901122, 43.01592861164031), 4258) LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.561619281768799, 43.01329278981061), 4258) LIMIT 1),
                        (SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.563893795013428, 43.00988801917453), 4258) LIMIT 1),
                        (SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.565395832061767, 43.01395175587418), 4258) LIMIT 1)]))

SELECT dijkstra.* FROM dijkstra
```

Y así me calcule todas las "x" e "y" de los puntos del ARRAY. 
La función que me ha puesto usted se acerca mucho al resultado que quiero, pero necesito el último giro de tuerca. A ver como podría conseguir esa función.
Muchas gracias de nuevo por su respuesta, me es de gran ayuda.

Comment: entonces agrégale un parámetro a la función pacman(arreglo numeric[]) y dentro, en el FOREACH utiliza FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1, donde $1 se refiere al parámetro que pasas, asi podras pasar cualquier arreglo

Comment: Si, eso ya lo tengo preparado. Pero como le he mencionado antes, necesito que como resultado me de la geometría más cercana a esos puntos que se van metiendo en el ARRAY. Entonces no me vale el void, necesito devolver un valor BIGINT, que es el ID de la geometría más cercana. Gracias de nuevo, a ver si me puede orientar un poco con ese tema. Supongo que será una especie de función SETOF, pero no se como enfocarla. Gracias de antemano¡

Comment: no entiendo mucho la logica que me comenta, pero si lo necesita es devolver un valor debes cambiar el tipo de dato de la funcion por bigint, como lo comentas y al final de la funcion un return ese valor, te pongo un ejemplo debajo en una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function pacman () returns bigint -- en caso de retornar algo debes poner el tipo  de dato a retornar aca
as 
$$
DECLARE 
x numeric[];
arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
rec record;
resultado bigint;
 BEGIN

  FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr

   LOOP 
    RAISE notice 'x : %, y: % ' ,x[1],x[2];
     --EXECUTE
     WITH
vertices AS (
    SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT source FROM ways
        UNION
        SELECT target FROM ways)),

    dijkstra as ( SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
        'ways',

       ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x[1],x[2]), 4258) 
  LIMIT 1)]
 ))
 SELECT * into rec --debes poner la salida de llamada en una funcion, en este caso rec
     FROM dijkstra;

   RAISE notice 'rec : % ' ,rec;


   END LOOP;
          --calcula tu resultado y retornalo

   return resultado;
   END;
   $$
    language plpgsql;
```

ahora si es un conjunto de datos con setof resuelves

```
create or replace function pacman () returns setof bigint -- en caso de retornar algo debes poner el tipo  de dato a retornar aca
as 
$$
DECLARE 
x numeric[];
arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
rec record;
resultado bigint;
 BEGIN

  FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr

   LOOP 
    RAISE notice 'x : %, y: % ' ,x[1],x[2];
     --EXECUTE
     WITH
vertices AS (
    SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT source FROM ways
        UNION
        SELECT target FROM ways)),

    dijkstra as ( SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
        'ways',

       ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x[1],x[2]), 4258) 
  LIMIT 1)]
 ))
 SELECT * into rec --debes poner la salida de llamada en una funcion, en este caso rec
     FROM dijkstra;

   RAISE notice 'rec : % ' ,rec;
   --calcula tu resultado y retornalo
   return next resultado;

   END LOOP;

   END;
   $$
    language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nos estamos acercando. 
Mire, le pongo un ejemplo de toda la query donde quiero meter el LOOP a ver si me explico mejor.
Esta es mi función en SETOF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrk1_fromAtoB(
    IN edges_subset regclass,
    IN x numeric[],
    OUT seq INTEGER,
    OUT gid BIGINT,
    OUT name TEXT,
    OUT distancia_m NUMERIC,
    OUT distancia_total NUMERIC,
    OUT cost NUMERIC,
    OUT agg_cost NUMERIC,
    OUT azimuth FLOAT,
    OUT geom geometry
)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    final_query TEXT;
BEGIN

    final_query :=
        FORMAT( $$
            WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM %1$I 
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM %1$I)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
                    '%1$I',

                    ARRAY[(SELECT osm_id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%2$s, %3$s), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            )
            SELECT
                seq,
                dijkstra.gid,
                dijkstra.name,
                TRUNC (ways.length_m::numeric) AS distancia_m,
                TRUNC (sum(length_m::numeric) OVER (ORDER BY seq), 2) as distancia_total,
                ROUND (dijkstra.cost::numeric, 2) AS cost,
                ROUND (dijkstra.agg_cost::numeric, 2) as agg_cost,
                azimuth,
                route_geom AS geom
            FROM dijkstra JOIN ways USING (gid);$$,
        edges_subset, x);
    RAISE notice '%', final_query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE final_query;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Ahora lo que necesito es que en

```
(
                SELECT *
                FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
                    '%1$I',

                    ARRAY[(SELECT osm_id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%2$s, %3$s), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            )
```

El proceso del ARRAY:

```
ARRAY[(SELECT osm_id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%2$s, %3$s), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
```

Lo haga tantas veces como subconjuntos haya en el ARRAY de la consulta. Por Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia('ways', ARRAY[[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]])
```

Y la query haga esto:

```
SELECT *
                FROM pgr_dijkstravia(
                    '%1$I',

                    ARRAY[
(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877), 4258) LIMIT 1),
(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036), 4258) LIMIT 1),
(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974), 4258) LIMIT 1)
]
            )
```

Entonces para esto quiero el proceso FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $2
Pero no se muy bien como encajarlo en esta función.
Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.